# Analogue of the Chebyshev polynomials over C?

Tags: cv.complex-variables

I've been driven up a wall by the following question: let p be a complex polynomial of degree d.  Suppose that |p(z)|≤1 for all z such that |z|=1 and |z-1|≥δ (for some small δ>0).  Then what's the best upper bound one can prove on |p(1)|?  (I only care about the asymptotic dependence on d and δ, not the constants.)

For the analogous question where p is a degree-d *real* polynomial such that |p(x)|≤1 for all 0≤x≤1-δ, I know that the right upper bound on |p(1)| is |p(1)|≤exp(d√δ).  The extremal example here is p(x)=T<sub>d</sub>((1+δ)x), where T<sub>d</sub> is the d<sup>th</sup> Chebyshev polynomial.

Indeed, by using the Chebyshev polynomial, it's not hard to construct a polynomial p in z *as well as its complex conjugate z**, such that

(i) |p(z)|≤1 for all z such that |z|=1 and |z-1|≥δ, and

(ii) p(1) ~ exp(dδ).

One can also show that this is optimal, for polynomials in both z and its complex conjugate.

The question is whether one can get a better upper bound on |p(1)| by exploiting the fact that p is really a polynomial in z.  The fastest-growing example I could find has the form p(z)=C<sub>d,δ</sub>(1+z)<sup>d</sup>.  Here, if we choose the constant C<sub>d,δ</sub> so that |p(z)|≤1 whenever |z|=1 and |z-1|≥δ, we find that

p(1) ~ exp(dδ<sup>2</sup>)

For my application, the difference between exp(dδ) and exp(dδ<sup>2</sup>) is all the difference in the world!

I searched about 6 approximation theory books---and as often the case, they answer every conceivable question except the one I want.  If anyone versed in approximation theory can give me a pointer, I'd be incredibly grateful.

Thanks so much!
--Scott Aaronson

PS. The question is answered below by David Speyer.  For anyone who wants to see explicitly the polynomial implied by David's argument, here it is:

p<sub>d,δ</sub>(z) = z<sup>d</sup> T<sub>d</sub>((z+z<sup>-1</sup>)(1+δ)/2+δ),

where T<sub>d</sub> is the d<sup>th</sup> Chebyshev polynomial.

Comment: Scott:  Good question, but please register with MO.  Join the club!


Comment: @Scott: I am curious: what was the intended application of this result?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I may be missing something obvious here. Let $f(z, z^{*})$ be the polynomial in $z$ and $z^{*}$ of degree $d$ which achieves $\exp(d \delta)$. Let $g(z)$ be the Laurent polynomial obtained from $f$ by replacing $z^{*}$ by $z^{-1}$. On the unit circle, we have $f=g$.

Now, let $h$ be the polynomial $z^d g$. This is an honest polynomial, because we multiplied by a high enough power of $z$ to clear out all the denominators and, for $z$ on the unit circle, we have $|h|=|f|$.

Doesn't this mean that $h$ is a polynomial of degree $2d$, obeying your conditions, with $|h(1)| \sim \exp(d \delta)$?

Comment: In fact, it's a way to convert between the two questions in both directions.


Comment: Duhhhhhh ... thanks so much David!  And Greg, yes, I registered!  I'll see if I can return the karma by mentally unsticking someone else now.